# More elegant way to create an array, where each element is the index

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Is there more elegant way(LINQ or other) to initialize array like this?

```
 int[] result = new int[PageCount];
 for (int i = 0; i < PageCount; i++)
 {
      result[i] = i;
 }
 return result;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd use:

```
int[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, PageCount).ToArray();
```

It's not the speediest solution possible, but it's unlikely to be a bottleneck in most apps.